# request for member ‘insert’ in ‘x’, which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, allocator

I have a map variable called x which is defined as :

```
    std::map <std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>,
    MyAlloc<std::pair <std::string, std::string> > >
    x (std::less<std::string> (), MyAlloc <std::pair <std::string, std::string> > ());
```

where MyAlloc is my custom STL Allocator defined by me. When I try to insert a pair into the map, like :

```
    x.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("key","value"));
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
    error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘x’, which is of non-class type
   ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, 
    std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, MyAlloc<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>,
    std::basic_string<char> > > >(std::less<std::basic_string<char> > (*)(), 
    MyAlloc<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > > (*)())’
```

I don't get this error if I'm using the default constructor of the Allocator,  like :

```
    std::map <std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>,MyAlloc <std::pair <std::string, std::string> > > x;
```

I'm not sure whether the intialisation with the default constructor is correct.. ?

Thanks in advance .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword to look for here is "most vexing parse". The definition of `x` is parsed as a function declaration. [Wikipedia has an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) which mentions the exact same error message.

Comment: Exactly, I had missed it.. Completely..! Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a function `x`, not an object.

The default ctor would use the same comparison and allocator, so use that.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use a custom constructor of the allocator once this is working, which would be something like this : std::map <std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>,
    MyAlloc<std::pair <std::string, std::string> > >
    x (std::less<std::string> (), MyAlloc <std::pair <std::string, std::string> > (d));  I'm having a custom constructor in my custom allocator which can take d's type

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. how can x be a function..? It is an object of type std::map but just that it uses custom stl allocator rather than the default constructor.

Comment: @codinonwheels: Why do you think it's an object? It's definition is `return-type x(argumentType1, argumentType2)`. But once you use the _expression_ `(d)`, it's no longer a function definition. Function definitions only include expressions as default arguments.